How to corectly report gui bugs in ubuntu/gnome GUI?
I encountered more than one "gui crimes" in ubuntu, most likely coming from gnome. I tried to report bug before, but it's not something 99% of users can do even if they dedicate hours to it.
Is there any place or page where we can report and upvote problems, so the community can take it from there and forward it to particular projects and teams? I'm ubuntu user, I contributed some code to open source, but only in projects I understand.
I don't know know anything about gnome code and I don't have capacity nor dedication to study it. Yet, there are bugs which should be easy to fix and I wish to report them, just don't knot how.
I'm writing this post, because I want to report following bug, but don't know how.
I wantto add Wireguard VPN connection using this nice gui:

When I push + button to add pears (beside that it magically breaks screenshot shortcut) it opens popup, where I should paste some keys and ip's. The moment I click some place outside, the popup closes and all data I entered is gone. It's there for more than a year. I'm confident, that it's one liner fix and it just need right attention.
My question is more about reporting, rather than fixing it

The bug reporting process in Ubuntu is described in Report a problem in Ubuntu:

identify the relevant package
run ubuntu-bug ${package} (from a terminal, or the AltF2 prompt)
review the collected information, and click “Send”
your browser will open a Launchpad page to submit the bug, you will have to register there or log in if you already have an account
enter the bug description:

review potential duplicates
if no existing bug matches, continue entering the relevant information

The difficult part for GUI bugs is often identifying the relevant package... In this case, the package is gnome-control-center; see How to identify window by clicking in Wayland for help figuring that out.
So to report the issue, run ubuntu-bug gnome-control-center and follow the prompts. This will result in a bug in the Launchpad bug tracker for gnome-control-center, and other users will then be able to confirm it, add information etc.

I tried that, but it's GUI behavior, no error is logged, no prompt is shown to describe the problem. I don't think this will help solving the problem. And in general it's not solving the difficult part, which you did for me. Posting it here seems not working either.

There is no prompt to describe the problem; that happens in the browser (see the screenshot). And even though no error is logged, you can still describe the problem exactly as you did in the question. As far as “Posting it here seems not working either.”, you explicitly asked for help reporting the bug rather than fixing it, so it’s not surprising that no one here looked into fixing it.
